# Omit a directory when searching with find

Tags: linux, bash, shell, search, find

Searching whole system using:

```
find / -type f -size +100M -exec ls -lh {} \; | awk '{ print $9 "|| Size : " $5 }'
```

How can I omit a directory? I see -prune -o, but I am not sure how to format the option.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: `find / -type d -name 'directory_to_omit' -prune -o -type f ...`

Comment: [Don't use `ls` in scripts.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) If you really are on Linux, you want to use the `-printf` predicate of `find` to print out the fields you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
find / -path /path/to/ommit -prune -o -type f -size +100M -exec ...
#      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0):

From `man`:

> To ignore a whole directory tree,  use  -prune  rather
> than  checking every file in the tree.  For example, to skip the
> directory `src/emacs` and all files and  directories  under  it,
> and  print the names of the other files found, do something like
> this:
> `find . -path ./src/emacs -prune -o -print`
> Note that the pattern match test applies to the whole file name,
> starting from one of the start points named on the command line.